# Allocation of byte array with JNA

Tags: arrays, pointers, char, jna

I'm trying to develop a function to fill a byte array passed as an actual argument. I am following the example of the documentation of JNA but it is not working. The documentation says:

```
// Original C declaration allocate_buffer <br>
void (char ** bufp, int * lenp);

// Equivalent JNA mapping
void allocate_buffer (PointerByReference bufp, IntByReference lenp);

// Usage
PointerByReference PointerByReference pref = new ();
IntByReference IntByReference iref = new ();
lib.allocate_buffer (pref, iref);
Pref.getValue Pointer p = ();
byte [] buffer = p.getByteArray (0, iref.getValue ());
```

My function in C is:

```
__declspec (dllexport) void allocate_buffer (char ** bufp, int * lenp)
{
    char array [4];

    array [0] = 0;
    array [2] = 1;
    array [3] = 2;
    array [4] = 3;

    * bufp = array;
    * lenp = 4;
}
```

But when printing the array values are the results:
0 20 48 2

How to implement the function allocate_buffer properly?
Or is the problem is in Java code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Resolved:
The correct C function is:

__declspec(dllexport) void allocate_buffer(unsigned char **bufp, int* lenp)

{

```
    unsigned char *array = (unsigned char *)malloc(4*sizeof(unsigned char));

    array[0] = 0;
    array[1] = 1;
    array[2] = 2;
    array[3] = 3;

    *bufp = array;
    *lenp = 4;
```

}